# Вывод данных(комментарии) из mysql, выбрав сортировку(дата, имя, email)

Tags: php, html, mysql

В данный момент коментарии выводятся с помощью одного php кода:

```
$comments = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY date DESC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $comments[] = new Comment($row);
}
foreach ($comments as $c) {
    echo $c->showComment();
```

Как выводить мои комментарии сортируя по дате/имени/email используя эту форму:

```
<form id="order" action="order.php" method="post">
    <p><select name="hero[]">
            <option disabled>Сортировать по</option>
            <option value="Имени">Имени</option>
            <option value="E-mail">E-mail</option>
            <option selected value="Дате добавления">Дате добавления</option>
        </select></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя "эту" форму нельзя. Как минимум, надо давать осмысленные имена управляющим элементам формы. Плюс формы для поиска должны использовать метод GET

```
    <select name="sort">
        <option disabled>Сортировать по</option>
        <option value="name">Имени</option>
        <option value="email">E-mail</option>
        <option selected value="date">Дате добавления</option>
    </select>
```

После этого в скрипте прописать все возможные варианты сортировки и выбирать из них

```
$sort_fields = [
    'name' => 'имя поля в бд ASC',
    'email' => 'имя поля в бд ASC',
    'date' => 'date DESC',
];

$sort = $sort_fields[$_GET['sort']] ?? $sort_fields['date'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY $sort");
```

Если захочется менять направление сортировки, то добавить еще один такой же массив с ASC DESC

Comment: А почему `post` не может быть? Тогда просто придется обработать запрос на js в качестве ajax